# PHP mailer to send contact form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make my contact form working but i think there is some problem in my code.

I am not getting email. Here is my html code. Maybe i am doing wrong post method or any error in my whole code?

**HTML**

```
<form class="contact_form" action="send.php" method="POST" name="contact_form">
<ul>
    <li>
         <h2>Contact Us</h2>
         <span class="required_notification">* Denotes Required Field</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"  placeholder="John Doe" required />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required />
        <span class="form_hint">Proper format "name@something.com"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="website">Website:</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="http://johndoe.com" required pattern="(http|https)://.+"/>
        <span class="form_hint">Proper format "http://someaddress.com"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6" required ></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = 'Message from Reef website';
$to = 'test@yahoo.com';

$headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
$success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
}
?>
```

There is any php code to work with HTML FORM to post values to my email?
This Form has validation so i do not need validation in it, just browser pop up upon success!!

Comment: Do you get any PHP error? You should also debug the parameters sent to mail() function and if possible print them out for us, to check.

Comment: @ Prix I am testing it on my test domain

Comment: NO PHP ERROR, Just white page and no Email in my box :(

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server set up?

Comment: No its just a normal email services

Comment: and did you debug parameters sent to mail() function? If there is no apparent problem with them, maybe share them with us? (you can obfuscate your email address)

Comment: is your action url correct ? i mean did you check if the data is getting posted in your send.php or even if send.php is getting called ?

Comment: One more thing: mail() returns true/false values... Debug what do you get from mail() - true or false? But definitely do check parameters that are sent to mail() just before they're passed into the function. If parameters are ok and mail() returns true, then it's not problem in your logic. The posted code on it's own looks okey

Comment: start by checking if you can send email's using the mail function, make a very simple php file with `<?php if (mail('your@email.com', 'Test', 'Some message test', null,
   '-fyour@email.com')) { echo "YAY email sent"; } else { echo "BOOOO! Email failed!"; }` Then if it works, try to make the same with a sample of the data you tried to post to it.

Comment: I used this code: http://jsfiddle.net/H9cA2/  and i got the email in my box but in fields there is no data :( check snap: http://i43.tinypic.com/2vm9c1g.jpg

Comment: @DanVan on your first field you forgot to add `name="name"`

Comment: you have not given name attribute to your name input element..

Comment: `type="url"` and `type="email"` does not exist it should be `type="text"`

Comment: @Prix No.. we can use them.. see here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @GirishGowda yes you can that does not mean it works on all browser you should properly look at the symbols with an X like for example Firefox and IE which are widely used browsers.

Comment: I update the html with name"name" and type"text in some fields. Still no luck :(

Comment: "Whole Code" questions are normally considered off-topic on this website. Extensive discussion in comments is another sign that this is not a suitable question. Please improve, checkout the help section and ask-advice for improvement guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

I am not a fan of using the mail() because it does not always work.  Even if it does work, you may need to deal with email related issues like your message showing up in spam box.

I would do something like this...

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'jswan';                            // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->AddAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient    

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

Comment: Here I  wrote a detailed article with some code sample. - http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/01/how-to-create-contact-form-with-phpmailer-to-send-mails/

Answer (score 0):

see this may help you

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

for more [see here](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)